# Visual Studio not colour coding .cs text correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dotnetnuke

this may be a little difficult to explain, but I'll try.

I'm creating a DotNetNuke module in C#.  The text in the .cs files are not colour coded for some reason.  Comments are black, key words are black, all text is black.  As if Visual Studio is just reading the file as plain text.

Now when I create a VB module, everything is fine.  Comments green, key words blue.

I've added the following tag to web.config

But that still did not help.

I'm running VS 2008 express, and DotNetNuke 5.

I added the Module by right clicking at the root of the tree, then add new item, then DotNetNuke Dynamic Module.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Visual Studio express and Visual Studio Professional conflicted.  I uninstalled Professional and everything's fine.

Comment: I'm a little curious why you would uninstall Professional and keep Express. I imagine most people would do the opposite.

Comment: I had to make sure all development environments were the same.

Comment: I had the same problem with VS2012, it was a pre-installed dev machine that came with VS2012 express. 
I added VS2012 Ultimate and had the same problem as above.
Removing the Express version fixed it for me.
I think it's worth re-wording the question to remove the DotNetNuke comments as this is a specific problem with two installs of VS and you will probably get more up votes.